# wiringPiSetupSys - input pin state does not change

Tags: gpio, wiring, root, wiringpi

I try to port my GPIO project from quick2wire to WiringPi. My aim is to read the state of a photocell connected to pin 24 of my raspberry pi (model B, revision 2).

My code (python 3) looks like this:

```
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi
import time

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys()
# wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio() # it would work with this instead of wiringPiSetupSys()

counter = 0
status = "unknown"
while True:
    counter += 1
    light = wiringpi.digitalRead(24)
    if not light:
        status = "ON"
    else:
        status = "OFF"
    time.sleep(3)
    print('(' + str(counter) + ') ' + status)
```

When I `wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()` instead of `wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys()` the code works as expected. Using `wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys()` however the output doesn't change - it would stay `ON` or `OFF` no matter how the state of the photo cell changes.

I also made sure that the pin is exported

```
$ gpio exports
GPIO Pins exported:
   5: in   0  none
```

As I checked the state of the photocell with `gpio gpio -g read 24` in the shell, I can exclude the possibility of a hardware issue.

As I want to use the code in a web application, I would strongly prefer to use `wiringPiSetupSys()` as a non-root user.

Can you help me solve or analyze the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work in your code? I can't get my python script to output the status of the pin.

Comment: I decided to do the whole GPIO thing without a library like wiring pi. They all didn't work as expected and I didn't want some update to break the whole system. Also, using GPIO with plain python is not that hard. Find my code for reading a pin here (notice that I used an interrupt instead of looping the request, which should be advantageous in most cases): https://github.com/speendo/photocell/blob/7b467d7b64c4f2ed38056a68a9997b1d6bf11d68/photocell.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

The [gpio documentation](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/) clearly states

> This exports the given pin **(BCM-GPIO pin number)** as an input or output and makes it available for a user program running as the same user to use.

So to make it work, I had to do the following:

```
gpio unexport 5
gpio export 24 in
$ gpio exports
GPIO Pins exported:
  24: in   1  none
```